# Difficulty understanding the inverse of a function

Tags: calculus, inverse, inverse-function

Let $f(x) = x^2$. Then, the inverse of the function is given by 
$g(y) = \sqrt y$. When I try graphing $f(x)$ and $g(y)$, the output produces the parabola for $f(x)$ and the other half of the parabola where $x > 0$ for $g(y)$. Why isn't the graph outputting the desired result of $\sqrt x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $a(x)=x^2\;$is not one-to-one, so it doesn't have an inverse.

The function $b(x) = x^2,\;x\ge 0\;$ *is* one-to-one, and its inverse is $c(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Note that the graph of $b\;$is just the right half of the parabola $y=x^2$.

As regards the Desmos graph of $c(y)=\sqrt{y}$, since you used $y$ as the name of the independent variable, Desmos chose to use the $y$-axis as the input axis, and the $x$-axis as the output axis. Thus, the positive input direction is "up", not "right", and the positive output direction is "right", not "up". That only affects the visualization, not how $c$ maps inputs to outputs. To see the graph of $c$ in the usual way, just graph $c(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

If you have more questions, please ask, and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: I used desmos to graph both f(x) = x^2 and g(y) = sqrt(y) which should be the inverse. I understand the idea of one to one but i'm not understanding why g(y) just gives me the right side of the parabola instead of the desired square root function. I know I could just use g(x) = sqrt(x) but my textbook uses the notation g(y) = sqrt(y) which is throwing me off.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^2$ doesn't have an inverse. The function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has an inverse. which can be expressed as $h(x)=x^2,\;x\ge 0$. The function $h$ is the same as the function $f$, except the domain of $h$ is restricted to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Also, with regard to $g(y)=\sqrt{y}\;$versus$\;g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, the name of the independent variable doesn't matter. The rule of how to map inputs to outputs is the same.

Comment: @GustoCo $f(x) =  x^2$ doesn't have an inverse $function$, but it has an inverse $relation$; it is $g(x) = \pm \sqrt x$. Note that $g$ is not a function, since some $x$ values (all but $x = 0$) give you more than one output; things like this are called relations. If you graph $g(x) = \pm x$, you will get the horizontal parabola. And yes, it makes absolutely no difference if you do $g(x)$ or $g(y)$, as long as you consider, for all functions/relations (as they do), the horizontal axis as the input axis, and the vertical axis as the output axis.

Comment: Alright makes sense. Thanks everyone